# Network tab summary in chrome dev tools does not display the Load Time and DOMContentLoad time for the website under test

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, page-load-time

I am trying to calculate the time *after* performing an action(clicking Search button) *until* the time data gets loaded into the page. I am recording this action and can see lots of data in the Network tab with multiple API calls.

However in the summary section I can only see the following:
**Requests|transferred|resources** - see screenshot below

I cannot see the following data:
**Finish|DomContentLoaded|Load time**

Any help is appreciated[image]

I can see all the data in the network tab summary section for other websites,  but not for the website under test.

Comment: Devtools thinks the site is still loading its main DOM content. You can report it on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you were trying to analyze an iframe. I did not see timings too when I cleared the log and reloaded the iframe (via host page functionality).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I confirm that in my case it was an iframe. But how to see the time for an iframe is still a question

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this, I tried to do several searches and I did not find how to fix this problem.

Only solution I found was to clear the data and reinstall the browser.

That way it started working again.